# Get a value of a CSS variable via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-variables

Using `<input type="color">` without a *default value* seems result into an unuseful control (I tried with Firefox 53) because color never changes, while
adding default value, everything runs as expected ([working example](https://jsfiddle.net/m5buocca/)).

I actually use this value to populate a css variable such as:

```
const colors = [...document.querySelectorAll(".color-controls input[type=color]")];
colors[0].addEventListener("input", setFrontColor);    
docStyle.setProperty("--front-color", colors[0].value);
```

Constrain to have set a default value into HTML attribute force me to manually set it, while I would like to set `value` getting via JS current CSS variable "`--front-color`" value.

**How to get a value of a CSS variable via jQuery?**

Comment: Maybe attribute is an option for you. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/611/selectors/1987/attribute-selectors#t=201611261153211273435

Comment: I sincerely don't understand what you're meaning...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').css("color",'red')
console.log($('button').css("color"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>asd</button>
```

1. Use `.css()`
2. To set use `.css("color","red");`
3. to get use `.css("color");`

Comment: I'm sorry but I wrote that I'm using CSS Variables such as `--front-color`. I have to set (and get) value of a CSS variable and then apply its value also into html attribute `value` of `<input type="color">`